# NHibernate.MappingException: An association from the table table refers to an unmapped class: Int32

Tags: .net, nhibernate, exception, configuration

im starting whit Nhibernate and have managed to get a few examples working, but now the aplication im makin throws this exeption when Nhibernate load the configuration.

```
NHibernate.MappingException: An association from the table TBL_MARCADAS refers to an unmapped class: Int32
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompileForeignKeys(Table table, ISet done)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompile()
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
at BusinessLayer.entidad.inicializar() in D:\vault\BusinessLayer\entidad.vb:line 40
at BusinessLayer.TblEmpleado.getEmpleado(String ci) in D:\vault\BusinessLayer\TblEmpleado.vb:line 60
at BICWEBWS.Service1.get_minutosatraso(String str_CI) in D:\vault\BICWEBWS\App_Code\BICws.asmx.vb:line 7244
```

here is the entitiy

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports NHibernate.Collection
Imports NHibernate.Mapping
Imports Iesi.Collections

<NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Class(Table:="TBL_MARCADAS")> _
Public Class TblMarcadas
    Inherits entidad
    Private m_codgestion As Integer
    Private m_codperiodo As Integer
    Private m_coddiamarcada As Integer
    Private m_codempleado As Integer
    Private m_codhorario As Integer
    Private m_minAtrasos As Integer
    Private m_cantMarcadas As Integer
    Private m_horaUno As [String]
    Private m_horaDos As [String]
    Private m_horaTres As [String]
    Private m_horaCuatro As [String]
    Private m_horaCinco As [String]
    Private m_horaSeis As [String]
    Private m_diaLiteral As [String]


    Public Sub New()
        'MyBase.entidad()'

    End Sub

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.CompositeId(0, class:="BusinessLayer.TblMarcadas, BusinessLayer")> _
    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.KeyManyToOne(1, Name:="Codgestion", Column:="CODGESTION")> _
    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.KeyManyToOne(2, Name:="Codperiodo", Column:="CODPERIODO")> _
    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.KeyManyToOne(3, Name:="Coddiamarcada", Column:="CODDIAMARCADA")> _
    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.KeyManyToOne(4, Name:="Codempleado", Column:="CODEMPLEADO")> _
    Public Overridable Property Codgestion() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_codgestion
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_codgestion = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property()> _
    Public Overridable Property Codperiodo() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_codperiodo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_codperiodo = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property()> _
    Public Overridable Property Coddiamarcada() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_coddiamarcada
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_coddiamarcada = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property()> _
    Public Overridable Property Codempleado() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_codempleado
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_codempleado = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property()> _
    Public Overridable Property Codhorario() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_codhorario
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_codhorario = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column:="MIN_ATRASOS")> _
    Public Overridable Property MinAtrasos() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_minAtrasos
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_minAtrasos = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column:="CANT_MARCADAS")> _
    Public Overridable Property CantMarcadas() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_cantMarcadas
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_cantMarcadas = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column:="HORA_UNO")> _
    Public Overridable Property HoraUno() As [String]
        Get
            Return m_horaUno
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As [String])
            m_horaUno = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column:="HORA_DOS")> _
    Public Overridable Property HoraDos() As [String]
        Get
            Return m_horaDos
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As [String])
            m_horaDos = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column:="HORA_TRES")> _
    Public Overridable Property HoraTres() As [String]
        Get
            Return m_horaTres
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As [String])
            m_horaTres = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column:="HORA_CUATRO")> _
    Public Overridable Property HoraCuatro() As [String]
        Get
            Return m_horaCuatro
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As [String])
            m_horaCuatro = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column:="HORA_CINCO")> _
    Public Overridable Property HoraCinco() As [String]
        Get
            Return m_horaCinco
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As [String])
            m_horaCinco = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column:="HORA_SEIS")> _
    Public Overridable Property HoraSeis() As [String]
        Get
            Return m_horaSeis
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As [String])
            m_horaSeis = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property(Column:="DIA_LITERAL")> _
    Public Overridable Property DiaLiteral() As [String]
        Get
            Return m_diaLiteral
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As [String])
            m_diaLiteral = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As [Object]) As Boolean
        Return MyBase.Equals(obj)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return MyBase.GetHashCode()
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim s As [String] = ""

        s += "codgestion : " & m_codgestion.ToString() & vbLf
        s += "codperiodo : " & m_codperiodo.ToString() & vbLf
        s += "coddiamarcada : " & m_coddiamarcada.ToString() & vbLf
        s += "codempleado : " & m_codempleado.ToString() & vbLf
        s += "codhorario : " & m_codhorario.ToString() & vbLf
        s += "minAtrasos : " & m_minAtrasos.ToString() & vbLf
        s += "cantMarcadas : " & m_cantMarcadas.ToString() & vbLf
        If m_horaUno IsNot Nothing Then
            s += "horaUno : " & m_horaUno.ToString() & vbLf
        Else
            s += "horaUno : null" & vbLf
        End If
        If m_horaDos IsNot Nothing Then
            s += "horaDos : " & m_horaDos.ToString() & vbLf
        Else
            s += "horaDos : null" & vbLf
        End If
        If m_horaTres IsNot Nothing Then
            s += "horaTres : " & m_horaTres.ToString() & vbLf
        Else
            s += "horaTres : null" & vbLf
        End If
        If m_horaCuatro IsNot Nothing Then
            s += "horaCuatro : " & m_horaCuatro.ToString() & vbLf
        Else
            s += "horaCuatro : null" & vbLf
        End If
        If m_horaCinco IsNot Nothing Then
            s += "horaCinco : " & m_horaCinco.ToString() & vbLf
        Else
            s += "horaCinco : null" & vbLf
        End If
        If m_horaSeis IsNot Nothing Then
            s += "horaSeis : " & m_horaSeis.ToString() & vbLf
        Else
            s += "horaSeis : null" & vbLf
        End If
        If m_diaLiteral IsNot Nothing Then
            s += "diaLiteral : " & m_diaLiteral.ToString() & vbLf
        Else
            s += "diaLiteral : null" & vbLf
        End If
        Return s
    End Function

    Public Overridable Function GetTotalAtrasos(ByVal mes As Integer, ByVal periodo As Integer, ByVal CI As String) As Integer
        ' That's how the Session decide to save or to update; set NHMA.Id(UnsavedValue=x) to replace 0
        Dim session As NHibernate.ISession
        Try
            session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession()

            Dim sd As System.Collections.IList = session.Find("from TBL_MARCADAS")
            Dim total As Integer
            For Each marcada As TblMarcadas In sd
                total += marcada.MinAtrasos
            Next
            Return total
        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            If (session IsNot Nothing) Then
                session.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Function


End Class
```

and here is the table Script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_MARCADAS](
 [CODGESTION] [int] NOT NULL,
 [CODPERIODO] [int] NOT NULL,
 [CODDIAMARCADA] [int] NOT NULL,
 [CODEMPLEADO] [int] NOT NULL,
 [CODHORARIO] [int] NULL,
 [MIN_ATRASOS] [int] NULL,
 [CANT_MARCADAS] [int] NULL,
 [HORA_UNO] [char](10) NULL,
 [HORA_DOS] [char](10) NULL,
 [HORA_TRES] [char](10) NULL,
 [HORA_CUATRO] [char](10) NULL,
 [HORA_CINCO] [char](10) NULL,
 [HORA_SEIS] [char](10) NULL,
 [DIA_LITERAL] [char](10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [CODGESTION] ASC,
 [CODPERIODO] ASC,
 [CODDIAMARCADA] ASC,
 [CODEMPLEADO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

this is what the NHibernate.mappings serializer throws:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Generated from NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes on 2010-06-24 08:27:58Z.-->
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.0">
  <class name="BusinessLayer.TblEmpleado, BusinessLayer" table="TBL_EMPLEADO">
    <id name="codempleado">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Nombre" />
    <property name="ApellidoP" column="APELLIDO_P" />
    <property name="ApellidoM" column="APELLIDO_M" />
    <property name="FechaIngreso" column="FECHA_INGRESO" />
    <property name="Cargo" />
    <property name="SueldoActual" column="SUELDO_ACTUAL" />
    <property name="Foto" />
    <property name="Estadoempleado" />
    <property name="Codregional" />
    <property name="Codseguro" />
    <property name="Codhorario" />
    <property name="FechaNac" column="FECHA_NAC" />
    <property name="Sexo" />
    <property name="Ci" />
    <property name="Expedido" />
    <property name="Nacionalidad" />
    <property name="TipoTrabajador" column="TIPO_TRABAJADOR" />
  </class>
  <class name="BusinessLayer.TblMarcadas, BusinessLayer" table="TBL_MARCADAS">
    <composite-id class="TblMarcadas">
      <key-many-to-one name="Codgestion" column="CODGESTION" />
      <key-many-to-one name="Codperiodo" column="CODPERIODO" />
      <key-many-to-one name="Coddiamarcada" column="CODDIAMARCADA" />
      <key-many-to-one name="Codempleado" column="CODEMPLEADO" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="Codperiodo" />
    <property name="Coddiamarcada" />
    <property name="Codempleado" />
    <property name="Codhorario" />
    <property name="MinAtrasos" column="MIN_ATRASOS" />
    <property name="CantMarcadas" column="CANT_MARCADAS" />
    <property name="HoraUno" column="HORA_UNO" />
    <property name="HoraDos" column="HORA_DOS" />
    <property name="HoraTres" column="HORA_TRES" />
    <property name="HoraCuatro" column="HORA_CUATRO" />
    <property name="HoraCinco" column="HORA_CINCO" />
    <property name="HoraSeis" column="HORA_SEIS" />
    <property name="DiaLiteral" column="DIA_LITERAL" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

thanks very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found the problem.

i dont know why the acutomatic generation tool used key-many-to-one:

```
<composite-id class="TblMarcadas">
      <key-many-to-one name="Codgestion" column="CODGESTION" />
      <key-many-to-one name="Codperiodo" column="CODPERIODO" />
      <key-many-to-one name="Coddiamarcada" column="CODDIAMARCADA" />
      <key-many-to-one name="Codempleado" column="CODEMPLEADO" />
    </composite-id>
```

i just changed it for key-property.

maybe it was because of a foreign key whit this table?

any way hope this helps some one bye